# Dereference of a possibly null reference in Entity Framework 6 query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, .net-6.0

I have a .NET 6 project with nullable reference types enabled (`<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`). I have this EF entity:

```
public class PostFile {
  public Int32 UserId { get; set; }
  public Int32 PostId { get; set; }

  public virtual User? User { get; set; }
  public virtual Post? Post { get; set; }
}
```

I added `?` above to prevent this nullable warning:

```
Non-nullable property '...' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable.
```

Now, I have this Entity Framework 6 LINQ query:

```
var postFiles = context.postFiles.Where(x => x.User.Id == request.UserId);
```

... but I get the following warning:

```
Dereference of a possibly null reference.
```

... on this part of my query:

```
x.User.Id == ...
```

How can I fix this warning?

Comment: What is the table relationship between PostFile and User? (and where is the User property?) Is it guaranteed that each PostFile will have exactly one User (and never "no" User)?

Comment: Also, do you expect a PostFile to not have an associated Post? You'd only use `?` when you expect the value might be null. I wouldn't expect a PostFile to exist without a matching Post.

Comment: PostFile will always have a User and Post but I believe EF might, in same cases, not load the Post or File?

Comment: Maybe context.postfiles.Include(x => x.User).Where(.... https://entityframework.net/include

Answer (score 4):

You should mark navigation entities as nullable. You should not have lazy loading enabled, and therefore navigation properties can be returned as `null` from queries. Even if they are required in the database, your code doesn't have to load them.

In your query expressions, you can be certain that Entity Framework isn't going to execute them clientside, but parse an SQL query out of them.

Therefore:

```
.Where(x => x.User!.Id == request.UserId)
```

You can tell the compiler with `User!` that you know it won't be null there. Unless you enable clientside evaluation, but you shouldn't, and if you do, you'll need a null check there anyway.

As for usage of `PostFile.User`, as in:

```
var postFile = dbContext.PostFiles.FirstOrDefault(p => p....) ?? throw ...;
var user = postFile.User;
```

There it can be `null` if you didn't `Include(p => p.User)` and don't have lazy loading enabled, so `user` would need a null check before usage.

If you *do* use lazy loading, you can disable the warning:

```
#pragma warning disable CS8618 // EF initializes these properties through lazy loading
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
#pragma warning restore CS8618
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean something like:

```
public class PostFile {
    public Int32 UserId{ get; set; }
    public Int32 PostId { get; set; }

    public virtual User? User { get; set; }
    public virtual Post? Post { get; set; }
}
```

Your original issue is a warning that C#8 introduced with being more explicit with null-able reference types. For an entity, the above implementation is not valid unless these relationships are indeed optional, which would require their FK fields (UserId and PostId) to also be Null-able. They likely are *not* optional.

The main options to address this:

A) Turn off the feature. (Disable null-able references in the project)

B) Ask "forgiveness" for the fact that these should never be null, but will not be in a valid state on construction. (EF will manage them)

```
public class PostFile {
    public Int32 UserId{ get; set; }
    public Int32 PostId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Altering the model to mark navigation properties as null-able references is likely to cause all kinds of problems as with migrations it can, and will start replacing non-null-able FKs with null-able ones. To mark these references as Null-able and keep EF happy:

```
public class PostFile {
    public Int32? UserId{ get; set; }
    public Int32? PostId { get; set; }

    public virtual User? User { get; set; }
    public virtual Post? Post { get; set; }
}
```

Which is almost certainly *not* what you want in your domain, or even legal if UserId and PostId are part of a PK.

Personally I'm chalking this change in C# up as a "land mine" MS enabled initially by default, such as Client Side Evaluation in EF.  :)
I foresee many-a-StackOverflow questions around this warning or breaking changes, and many-a-client codebases littered with "!" forgiveness tags as older non-null-able objects/references are passed into code with null-able reference checks.

Answer (score 1):

What about `var postFiles = context.postFiles.Where(x => x.User != null && x.User.Id == request.UserId);`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
public class PostFile {
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

And call

```
var postFiles = context.postFiles.Where(x => x.User.Id == request.UserId).Include(x => x.Post);
```

Comment: No. Not marking these properties as nullable makes the compiler emit warnings that they might not be initialized, which is true.